# Error loading and running event receiver Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.PublishingWebEventReceiver in Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing

Tags: development, permissions, publishing, event-handlers

I am seeing the following error in my application log:

```
Error loading and running event receiver Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.PublishingWebEventReceiver in Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c. Additional information is below.
```

Xml

```
: <nativehr>0x80070005</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>Access denied.

<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-SharePoint Products-SharePoint Foundation" Guid="{6FB7E0CD-52E7-47DD-997A-241563931FC2}" /> 
  <EventID>6875</EventID> 
  <Version>14</Version> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>7</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x4000000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2011-05-23T09:04:09.982297200Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>600841</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation ActivityID="{EFB60607-0455-4B31-9DB9-562DE66557CB}" /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="4436" ThreadID="3624" /> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer>server</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="S-1-5-21-1644491937-1078145449-725345543-5574" /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data Name="string0">Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.PublishingWebEventReceiver</Data> 
  <Data Name="string1">Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Data> 
  <Data Name="string2">: <nativehr>0x80070005</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>Access denied.</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

How can I track down to see why I am getting the Access Denied?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you have some custom conponent that is trying to load the Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing asssembly.

Becuase Publishing features are not allowed as part of the SharePoint Foundation platform.
Publishing features are only available in SharePoint Server.